# SQLite sqlite3pp C++ api: how to load all sqlite3pp::transactions that can be found in db into some vector or set?

Tags: c++, sqlite, transactions

So I found out that [sqlite3pp](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite3pp/wiki/UsagePage)  C++ SQLite db engine API has some concept of rollbackable transactions. I wonder if thows transactions can be extracted from db file for example after application restart? And if so how to load all of tham in order thay have happened into some vector? (This would make creation of db items version and revision control easy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the SQLite 3 docs:

> If sqlite3_close() is invoked while a transaction is open, the transaction is automatically rolled back.

This is true whether you're using the API directly or indirectly with sqlite3pp. So you cannot preserve DB transactions across application restarts (since database connections are application-specific).

I have no idea what would happen if you simply exited the application without closing the database, but I'm pretty sure the transaction would be lost.

Comment: @Kabumbus: The purpose of database transactions is to ensure that a specific series of commands are all either executed or not executed. Virtually every Wiki is implemented on top of an SQL database of some kind, so it's very doable. But you can't use transactions to actually do it.